# Symfony Custom helper with parameters

Tags: php, service, symfony-3.4

I'm developing a Symfony App and I need to code a helper as a service. First of all I've defined 3 constants as parameters to take them in all web app

This is part of parameters content:

```
parameters:
    api.public.key: '123456789'
    api.private.key: 'ABCDEFGHI'
    api.timestamp: '1'
```

Now I'm going to develope my custom helper `Utils/ApiHelper.php` but I need that my helper can recieve this 3 parameters.

I've my Helper defined my helper as service like this:

```
services:
    api.helper:
        class: AppBundle\Utils\ApiHelper
        public: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add [arguments](https://symfony.com/doc/3.2/service_container.html#service-parameters) to your custom service:

```
services:
    api.helper:
        class: AppBundle\Utils\ApiHelper
        public: true
        arguments: ['%api.public.key%', '%api.private.key%', '%api.timestamp%']
```

And then pass it as constructor arguments:

```
class ApiHelper
{
    // ...
    public function __construct(string $publicKey, string $privateKey, string $timeStamp)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```